# How can I remove duplicate cells of any row in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, cell

I need to update a pandas DataFrame as below. Is it possible by any means?
[I highly appreciate all of your time and endeavors. Sorry that my question arose confusion among you. I tried to update the question. Thanks again]

Sample1:

```
import pandas as pd    
#original dataframe
data = {'row_1': ['x','y','x','y'], 'row_2': ['a', 'b', 'a', None]}
data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
print(data)

#desired dataframe from data
data1 = {'row_1': ['x','y'], 'row_2': ['a', 'b']}
data1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1, orient='index')
print(data1)
```

Sample 2:

```
import pandas as pd    
#original dataframe
data = {'row_1': ['x','y','p','x'], 'row_2': ['a', 'b', 'a', None]}
data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
print(data)

#desired dataframe from data
data1 = {'row_1': ['x','y','p'], 'row_2': ['a', 'b']}
data1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1, orient='index')
print(data1)
```

Comment: What do you mean remove duplicate cells from any row? How would that look in regards to the columns? Are you trying to remove columns based off of cells that share a common value being in the same row?

Comment: @Chowlett2, I don't want to remove any row or column. I just want that in any row duplicate values will be set to 'nan' or removed. I

Comment: Given the accepted answer, your expected output is different from what you present here. Please edit your question to put in the correct expected output so that your question may be helpful to other users in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.transpose().dropna().unique().transpose(), axis=1)
```

This is what you are looking for. Use `dropna` to get rid of `NaN`'s and then only keep the `unique` elements. Apply this logic to each row of the dataframe to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though it doesn't return a DataFrame maintaining the original schema, for my work, it will fulfill the purpose. I will need some processing on it.

Comment: @suptagni As per your question this is what you expected. If you are thinking some sort of column specification then the task becomes a bit tricky but you didn't mention that.

Comment: @suptagni but in your own question, you did not ask for that as the desired output. That's why I was asking you about dropping columns, because you quite literally drop columns in your desired output

Answer (score 0):

you can use `duplicated` method. checkout this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#:%7E:text=df.duplicated(keep%3D%27last%27)) for an example on pandas' API reference

Comment: I checked the link before posting. Unfortunately, I couldn't get how I can use duplicated method for this desired output!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this,

```
data = data.T.loc[data.T["row_1"].drop_duplicates().index, :].T
```

Output -

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row_1 | x | y |
| row_2 | a | b |

Comment: Thanks @Zero Though it works for the given sample, it doesn't for: data = {'row_1': ['x','y','p','x'], 'row_2': ['a', 'b', 'a', None]}

Comment: @suptagni The code only removes duplicate element from the first row. You want it for all? Share the desired output for this new example in the question itself.

Comment: @suptagni but in your own question, you did not ask for that as the desired output. That's why I was asking you about dropping columns, because you quite literally drop columns in your desired output

Comment: @Chowlett2 I had the same doubts